# How to fix the translation tool with local storrage for IE and Edge

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, local-storage, microsoft-edge

I've written a translation tool in JS for my website. It works perfectly for all browsers except IE and Edge. I am working with local storage to save the selected language. The Edge console tells me the problem is in the line

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
```

Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

```
var lang;

function translateTexts() {

if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (window.localStorage.getItem("lang") == null) {
        window.localStorage.setItem("lang", 'de');
    }

  var lang = window.localStorage.getItem("lang");

    if (lang == 'de') {
        document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex = "0";
    }
    if (lang == 'en') {
        document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex = "1";
    }
} else {
    lang = "de";
}
```

Unknown Error in line 6:

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
```

Answer (score 0):

> if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

This line of code is used to check whether the browser support LocalStorage or not.

With reference to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), we can see that the LocalStorage support IE 8+ and Microsoft Edge 12+. You could check your browser version and make sure it support localStorage.

I have created a sample using the following code:

```
<div>
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="us">us</option>
        <option value="de">de</option>
        <option value="en">en</option>
    </select>
</div>
<script>
    var lang;
    function translateTexts() {

        if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
            if (window.localStorage.getItem("lang") == null) {
                window.localStorage.setItem("lang", 'de');
            }

            var lang = window.localStorage.getItem("lang");
            debugger;
            if (lang == 'de') {
                document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex = "1";
            }
            if (lang == 'en') {
                document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex = "2";
            }
            console.log("support storage");
        } else {
            lang = "de";
            console.log("de");
        }

    }

    translateTexts();
</script>
```

It code works well on my side (using Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0 and IE 11.116.18362.0 version),  and the result like this.[image]

So, please check your javascript code, whether there have another script will cause this issue.

Besides, You could try to clear the browser cache, history and the browser data, then re-test your code (also you could create a new sample to test above code).